# DFS just not replicating?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dfs-r

I have been using DFS quite a lot in the past always to good success.

Now I have a funny issue and I am lost.

- 2008 R2 Sp1 on both ends.
- Same domain.
- There is a folder on A that is replicated. It has a folder Data in it (and in some tim other folder). This folder has 168 files in 6 folders with a total size of 158gb.
- On the other end (this is a site to site replciatio nbetween two locations, which shall basically pull data from a data center into the office for backup) I have 44,7gb, 55 files in 6 folders.

Dfsrdiag shows in both directions no backlog, partners in sync. No errors show up.

There is a 40gb staging area in place. Files are mostly 1.5gb each (some are smaller below 50mb). Event losw hows nothing - it seems DFS just decided to not replicate those files.

Anyone an idea how to debug this? I have another 45gb coing in that need to move in a week 2nd of the month).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest checking the basics first:

1. Is the correct node designated as the DFS Replication primary?  Maybe it's backwards?
2. Is the replication topology correct and set (did you initially set it up with no topology and forgot to create the connections)?
3. Make sure that the files in question do not have replication filters.

Barring these, have you checked to see if any newly placed files replicate properly?  If so, perhaps you can just manually copy the remainder of the existing files to the target and monitor it from there?

Comment: I wiped the replication and reinitiated it... worked fine afterwards. No idea still what it was.